# "from when he was younger" or "from the time he was younger" or "when he was younger"

Tags: sentence-construction

(1) Although I haven't seen him for years, I still remember how he looked **from when** he was younger.

(2) Although I haven't seen him for years, I still remember how he looked **from the time** he was younger.

(3) Although I haven't seen him for years, I still remember how he looked **when** he was younger.

(4) Although I haven't seen him for years, I still remember his younger face.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: These are all OK, and all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

*Although I haven't seen him for years, I still remember* ***how he looked when he was younger***. is correct

although I would have written

> *Although I haven't seen him for years, I still remember **what he looked like** when he was younger.*